# asp.net MVC application with custom dateformat in all culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-datepicker

i have a MVC application which sets english and german culture based on the login. 
now i need to give a option to enduser to select the Datetime format they want , so when a user select mm/dd/yyyy format then all the datepicker in application should show in that format irrespective of culture.

How to achieve this, i am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: you need to probably store it in the DB or cookie or some caching system so you refer to it in subsequent requests and find the culture setting the user wanted then apply it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did before was had the formats saved in a table somewhere in my database and before initializing the view I passed the format to the view. You will notice that bootstrap-datepicker will take the format when initializing it. So you can do it via an ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
       format: data.DateFormat
    })
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Or if you'd like to set the format when returning the view then you can use Razor to replace it with the format like below:

```
<input class="datepicker" data-date-format="@Model.DateFormat">
```

I followed the docs here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#configuration